# WPF - Trying to Add an Icon to my Window but getting a strange error

Tags: c#, wpf

XamlParseException occured
Provide value on 'System.Windows.BAML.2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception

I looked up examples of how to add an icon and it seems simple enough.  How can I fix this?

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="DTV_Red_Zone_Channel.MainWindow"
        Title="DirecTV Red Zone Channel" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Initialized="WindowInitialized" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Icon="RCS_Generic.ico">  <---- Where it's Erroring
```

Comment: What is the InnerException of the parsing exception?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that as I don't see an "InnerException" anywhere in the error message... the only other detail it says is that the error occurred on line number 6 and line position 41

Comment: Look at the exception details in the debugger - there's an InnerException property, which will often give you more information.

Comment: ah... it says it cannot locate resource 'rcs_generic.ico' but i put it in the main directory AND where the executable folder is... so where would i put it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ah... it says it cannot locate resource 'rcs_generic.ico' but i put it in the main directory AND where the executable folder is... so where would i put it then?

You need to include the `RSC_Generic.ico` in your project (at the root, given your XAML), **and** make sure that it's properties are set to use a `Build Action` of `Resource`.

Comment: didn't know I had to actually add it to the project.  thanks!